# In Unity OpenXR environment, how to reset the player position to center?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, openxr

We're creating a game for graduate college. I'm making a flight shooting game in unity on VR.

The problem is that reset player (aircraft) position to current player's position in real.

Currently, my player object's structure is...

```
Player
    > XR Origin
        > Camera Offset
            > VR Camera
            > controllers.. etc
    > Aircraft Model
```

Hierarchy Capture Image:

[image: Hierarchy Capture Image]

I tried to reset position.

But many tutorials are not flight game, and most of tutorials are re-centered the prepared transform's position.

I want to recenter to current player's real position (in vr).

I know that is possible to recenter in the vr's built in function.
But I want to recenter in unity runtime.

Any one has solution? Or is there any method one can call at runtime to recenter the position using vr's built in function?

I using Unity 2022.2.19f, OpenXR package, Oculus Quest 2 (I do not directly use Oculus SDK like OVR...)

Sorry for my poor English skill.. because I'm korean.. :<

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**MainCamera --> head**

**XR Origin --> origin**

**Desired object for center position --> target**

```
public class ReCenterXROrigin : MonoBehaviour
{
   public Transform head;
   public Transform origin;
   public Transform target;

   private Vector3 offset;
   private Vector3 targetForward;
   private Vector3 cameraForward;
   private float angle;


   private void Start()
   {
      Recenter();
   }

   public void Recenter()
   {
      offset = head.position - origin.position;
      offset.y = 0;
      origin.position = target.position + offset;
      
      targetForward = target.forward;
      targetForward.y = 0;
      cameraForward = head.forward;
      cameraForward.y = 0;

      angle = Vector3.SignedAngle(cameraForward, targetForward, Vector3.up);
      
      origin.RotateAround(head.position, Vector3.up, angle);
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there no API call for this.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this.

```
public void ResetPositionAndRotation() {
    _cameraOffset.position = new Vector3(0, 1.6f, 0);
    _cameraOffset.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
    
    Quaternion rotation = Camera.main.transform.rotation;
    _cameraOffset.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(
        _cameraOffset.rotation.eulerAngles.x,
        360f - rotation.eulerAngles.y, 
        _cameraOffset.rotation.eulerAngles.z);
    
    Vector3 newGlobPosition = Camera.main.transform.position;
    newGlobPosition.y  = -_cameraOffset.position.y;
    _cameraOffset.position = -newGlobPosition;
}
```